# Lines cannot be deleted

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5, tradingview-api

I have some lines and labels on my last candle indicating certain price levels. I tried to delete all labels and lines and then plot them again. But for some reason the same code works fine in case of the labels but the first line drawn on the chart stays there.

Code:

```
if barstate.islast or bar_index == 0
    while array.size(label.all) > 0
        label.delete(array.first(label.all))
        
    while array.size(line.all) > 0
        line.delete(array.first(line.all))

    if showPullingLines == true
        PullUpPriceLine := line.new(bar_index-2, PullUpPrice, bar_index, PullUpPrice, color=color.purple, width=1)
        lblPullUpPriceLine := label.new(bar_index-2, PullUpPrice, "Pull up price:\n" + str.tostring(Truncate2(PullUpPrice)), color = color.purple, textcolor = color.white,style = label.style_label_lower_right)
        PullDownPriceLine := line.new(bar_index-2, PullDownPrice, bar_index, PullDownPrice, color=color.purple, width=1)
        lblPullDownPriceLine := label.new(bar_index-2, PullDownPrice, "Pull down price:\n" + str.tostring(Truncate2(PullDownPrice)), color = color.purple, textcolor = color.white,style = label.style_label_upper_right)
```

See screenshot:

[image: screenshot]

Comment: My workaround so far is that before plotting new lines I check the line in question whether it exists or not and delete it if needed. But it would be more simple if I just delete them all and plot only what is needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this :

```
a_allLines = line.all
if array.size(a_allLines) > 0
    for i = 0 to array.size(a_allLines) - 1
        line.delete(array.get(a_allLines, i))
```

Comment: I think the problem is not related to this both the while cycle and the for cycle  works fine except in one case (where the price is between my sell  target and buy target). I think somewhere I missed a block or case to evaluate where the deletion of the lines should occur. Anyway, thank you for your kind help.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).